# GridView column losing hyperlink when looping through rows

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have an asp.net page written with vb.net that has a gridview table. The table is setup to have a checkbox column for each row. If this checkbox is checked for a row, I do some additional things. One of the other columns also includes a hyperlink on the text for each cell in that column.

I have a button on the page that will loop through and programmatically check each one of the checkboxes. The button does this correctly; however, it also removes the hyperlink from the other column for some reason. Any ideas why?

Here is the code where I set the hyperlinks for the hyperlink column:

```
Protected Sub gridData_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gridData.RowDataBound
    'When a row is added to the data grid view we need to add the hyperlink to the zipname column
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim cell As TableCell = e.Row.Cells(4)
        Dim lnk As HyperLink = New HyperLink

        'Set properties of the link
        lnk.NavigateUrl = cell.Text
        lnk.Text = cell.Text

        'Format the filename, filepath, zipname, and username to be lowercase
        e.Row.Cells(1).Text = LCase(e.Row.Cells(1).Text)
        e.Row.Cells(3).Text = LCase(e.Row.Cells(3).Text)
        e.Row.Cells(4).Text = LCase(e.Row.Cells(4).Text)
        e.Row.Cells(5).Text = LCase(e.Row.Cells(5).Text)


        'Add the hyperlink
        cell.Controls.Clear()
        cell.Controls.Add(lnk)
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is the code for the check all button:

```
 Protected Sub cmdCheckAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCheckAll.Click
    'Check all of the download checkboxes

    For Each row As GridViewRow In gridData.Rows
        CType(row.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox).Checked = True
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As is the usual case with Dynamic Controls, All the dynamically created Hyperlinks in RowDataBound event needs to be recreated every postback.

So, there are 2 options.

1.)  Either bind your `GridView` on every postback :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       gridData.DataBind();

    }
```

OR

2.) Turn off `ViewState` for your `GridView`::

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridData" EnableViewState="false" ... />.
```

On using any of above options, the `OnRowDataBound` event is executed each time postback happens, thus recreating the Dynamic controls. Now you can access the `Hyperlinks` in your button click event.

Check properly which one of above options is best for your application.